# show inequality by using bramble hilbert lemma

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices $x_1,x_2,x_3$. $|\mathbb{T}|$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{T}$.
I want to show the following inequality.
\begin{equation}
(\forall g \in H^2(\mathbb{T})) |\int _{\mathbb{T}} g(x)dx - \frac{|\mathbb{T}|}{3}\sum _{k=1}^3 g(x_i)|\leq\delta\times |\mathbb{T}|\times |g| _{H^2(\mathbb{T})}
\end{equation}
for some $\delta \in ]0,+\infty[$.
I would like to show this inequality by using the Bramble-Hilbert lemma. Could somebody help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: ? Apply Bramble-Hilbert to the functional on the left. You need to verify that the left hand side is zero for polynomials of degree $\le 1$.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can verify that the left hand side is zero for polynomials of degree smaller than 1?